# owl carousel item amount config being ignored

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

See my example below:

```js
$(function(e) {
  $("#blog-slider").owlCarousel({
    // mobile
    nav: false,
    navText: '',
    items: 2,
    dots: false,
    responsiveClass:true,
    stagePadding: 30,
    // desktop
    responsive:{
        980:{
            // this isn't being listened to why!?
            items:6,

            slideBy: 6,
            stagePadding: 0,
            nav: true,
            dots: false,
            navText: ''
        }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.homepage-slider {
    overflow: visible;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    padding: 20px 41px 20px 40px;
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div id="blog-slider" class="homepage-slider owl-carousel">
          <div class="homepage-slider__item homepage_blog_carousel1">
             <a href="#">
               <div>
                  <img class="alignnone" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" alt="" width="701" height="394">
               </div>
             </a>
             <a href="#">
               <div class="homepage-slider__interior post-tag">
                  category tag
               </div>
             </a>
             <a href="#">
               <div class="homepage-slider__interior post-title">
                  A post title goes here
               </div>
               <div class="homepage-slider__interior post-date">
                  November 14, 2018
               </div>
             </a>
          </div>
          <div class="homepage-slider__item homepage_blog_carousel1">
             <a href="#">
               <div>
                  <img class="alignnone" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" alt="" width="701" height="394">
               </div>
             </a>
             <a href="#">
               <div class="homepage-slider__interior post-tag">
                  category tag
               </div>
             </a>
             <a href="#">
               <div class="homepage-slider__interior post-title">
                  A post title goes here
               </div>
               <div class="homepage-slider__interior post-date">
                  November 14, 2018
               </div>
             </a>
          </div>
          <div class="homepage-slider__item homepage_blog_carousel1">
             <a href="#">
               <div>
                  <img class="alignnone" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" alt="" width="701" height="394">
               </div>
             </a>
             <a href="#">
               <div class="homepage-slider__interior post-tag">
                  category tag
               </div>
             </a>
             <a href="#">
               <div class="homepage-slider__interior post-title">
                  A post title goes here
               </div>
               <div class="homepage-slider__interior post-date">
                  November 14, 2018
               </div>
             </a>
          </div>
          <div class="homepage-slider__item homepage_blog_carousel1">
             <a href="#">
               <div>
                  <img class="alignnone" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" alt="" width="701" height="394">
               </div>
             </a>
             <a href="#">
               <div class="homepage-slider__interior post-tag">
                  category tag
               </div>
             </a>
             <a href="#">
               <div class="homepage-slider__interior post-title">
                  A post title goes here
               </div>
               <div class="homepage-slider__interior post-date">
                  November 14, 2018
               </div>
             </a>
          </div>
          <div class="homepage-slider__item homepage_blog_carousel1">
             <a href="#">
               <div>
                  <img class="alignnone" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" alt="" width="701" height="394">
               </div>
             </a>
             <a href="#">
               <div class="homepage-slider__interior post-tag">
                  category tag
               </div>
             </a>
             <a href="#">
               <div class="homepage-slider__interior post-title">
                  A post title goes here
               </div>
               <div class="homepage-slider__interior post-date">
                  November 14, 2018
               </div>
             </a>
          </div>
          <div class="homepage-slider__item homepage_blog_carousel1">
             <a href="#">
               <div>
                  <img class="alignnone" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" alt="" width="701" height="394">
               </div>
             </a>
             <a href="#">
               <div class="homepage-slider__interior post-tag">
                  category tag
               </div>
             </a>
             <a href="#">
               <div class="homepage-slider__interior post-title">
                  A post title goes here
               </div>
               <div class="homepage-slider__interior post-date">
                  November 14, 2018
               </div>
             </a>
          </div>
          <div class="homepage-slider__item homepage_blog_carousel1">
             <a href="#">
               <div>
                  <img class="alignnone" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" alt="" width="701" height="394">
               </div>
             </a>
             <a href="#">
               <div class="homepage-slider__interior post-tag">
                  category tag
               </div>
             </a>
             <a href="#">
               <div class="homepage-slider__interior post-title">
                  A post title goes here
               </div>
               <div class="homepage-slider__interior post-date">
                  November 14, 2018
               </div>
             </a>
          </div>
          <div class="homepage-slider__item homepage_blog_carousel1">
             <a href="#">
               <div>
                  <img class="alignnone" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" alt="" width="701" height="394">
               </div>
             </a>
             <a href="#">
               <div class="homepage-slider__interior post-tag">
                  category tag
               </div>
             </a>
             <a href="#">
               <div class="homepage-slider__interior post-title">
                  A post title goes here
               </div>
               <div class="homepage-slider__interior post-date">
                  November 14, 2018
               </div>
             </a>
          </div>
      </div>
```

I specify in my desktop (980+ breakpoint) to only show 6 items. It is being ignored and showing 8. Why? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was serving an old version of the **owl carousel** CSS (1.3.3)

Using the correct version (2.2.1) resolved this issue.